# web data capture .NET server

Tags: javascript, .net

I'm trying to do a data extraction from a .NET web server but I cannot send the data correctly.

If I post the data with a normal html form I can show the correct page with the information I need.

The html form contains valid fields as __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION and other fields to query the server.

This form works fine but I cannot capture any data.

If I try to send the same data (with the POST method) using javascript with `ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");`   or using `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")` in classic ASP, I receive in return from the server the message:

> ''The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.,, or the correct page w/o the result of the query (page empty).

I think the problem is in the header, so I've tried to send in many formats but w/o success.

Any help ?
the following is the code that correctly send data

```
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="http://geon....neNew.aspx"  id="aspnetForm">
    <input type="text" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />`enter code here`
    <input type="text" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/--------- here the key --"/>
    <input type="text" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/--------- here the key --" />


 <br>
 DUG:
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDUG" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDUG" <td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TableCell3">

 <br>   
 Denomin.:
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDenominazione" type="text" value="indipendenza" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDenominazione" >

 <br>
 Civico:
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCivico" type="text" value="34" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCivico" />

 <br>
 Espon:
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtEsponente" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEsponente" >

 <br>
 CAP:
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCAP" type="text" maxlength="5" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCAP"  >

 <br>Prov.:
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSiglaProv" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSiglaProv" />

<br>
 Comune:
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtComune" type="text" value="gazzo" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtComune" >


                <b>Informazioni&nbsp;addizionali</b></p>

                <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkUffRecapito" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkUffRecapito" tabindex="9" />
                <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkUffRecapito">Centro/Presidio decentrato di distribuzione</label>
<br>

                <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCodPre" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkCodPortalettere" tabindex="10" />
                <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCodPre">Numero Potere</label>
                <br>            

 <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkAmbigui" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkAmbigui" tabindex="11" />
 <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkAmbigui">Scarta in caso di indirizzi ambigui</label>
 <br>

 <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmdNormalizza" value="Normalizza" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdNormalizza"   />
 <br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---- and this is the code that capture the data in the form but send data incorrectly:

```
<script>
var req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
req1.open('GET', document.location, false);
req1.send(null);
var headers = req1.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
//alert(headers);
document.write(headers+'<p>');


var formElements=document.getElementById("aspnetForm").elements;    
var postData={};
var qs;
qs="";
for (var i=0; i<formElements.length; i++) {
    if (formElements[i].type!="submit")
        {
            qs=qs +  formElements[i].name + "=" + formElements[i].value + "&" ;
        //  alert(formElements[i].name);
        }
}
        //qs = qs.substring(0, qs.length - 1);
        qs=qs +"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmdNormalizza=Normalizza"
        document.write(qs);

        var req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        req.open('POST', 'http://geono....LineNew.aspx', false);
        //req.open('POST', 'http://vepdcm1sa01/exps/x2/read.asp', false);
        //req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain;');
        req.setRequestHeader('cache-control','private');
        //req.setRequestHeader('content-length','162107');
        req.setRequestHeader('content-type','text/plain');
        req.setRequestHeader('server','microsoft-iis/7.5');
        //req.setRequestHeader('date',' tue, 19 feb 2019 10:17:55 gmt');

        req.send(qs);
        if(req.status == 200)
            document.write(req.responseText);

</script>
```

Comment: we have no idea what your code is doing, but asp.net webforms pages contain protections against doing exactly what you're trying to do. You're probably running up against that.

Comment: Thanks for your relply, but other times I worked around similar problem and I've found a solutions only this time is different, I do not know why maybe the problem in the header of the data sent

Comment: Ok. Well that's interesting speculation but without any code or sample data or detailed debugging info we have no way to help you determine the real problem.

Comment: What code? Please edit your question if you wish to add code. We will also need some actual sample HTML of the page(s) you're trying to work with, so we know what you are sending and receiving.

Comment: Looking at your newly added code, this is exactly what the inbuilt safeguards of asp.net webforms is trying to protect against, unauthorized form posts from an external resource.